# Download Image send Keys Selenium Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, download, webdriver, key

Here is the deal, I have a link that is just an image, and I need to download this to a specific place on my computer with a specific name.

I have tried to send keys, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, `Name_of_the_file`, enter and it won't go.

It has to be with the Webdriver, via Selenium.

The link is this one:

```
 http://acervo.estadao.com.br/publicados/1973/03/22/m/19730322-30054-nac-0114-999-116-not.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code to save required image:

```
import requests

URL = "http://acervo.estadao.com.br/publicados/1973/03/22/m/19730322-30054-nac-0114-999-116-not.jpg"
with open("/Path/to/saved/file.jpg", "wb") as f:
    f.write(requests.get(URL).content)
```

If you want to do save picture via Selenium, try:

```
driver.get(URL)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("/Path/to/saved/file.jpg")
```

Note that this method will save the whole page as it appears in browser (image with the background)

Comment: The only problem for the selenium is that the quality of the screenshot is pretty bad, i need a good quaility for OCR